# How do I handle a file upload from a mobile application on the server side?

Tags: java, web-applications, mobile

I want to prototype a server component that accepts and handles file uploads from a mobile application (should not matter what platform the phone's running). The files in question are most likely just photos, so the file size should not be that big.

I'm looking for technology/tool/library recommendations or pointers. I'm not sure where to start. I haven't set up anything on the server-side yet so I'm not sure what I don't know. Something Java-related would definitely ease me into setting up the prototype quickly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use servlet on server-side to receive files, to generate unique names for these files and keep them preferable on file system (not on database). For example you can see
http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html